# Cannot pair Galaxy S8 with PC

Tags: bluetooth, samsung-galaxy-s-8

My PC is an old Sony Vaio SVF model. The last official supported OS is Windows 8.1.

The PC has a Broadcom 43142 Bluetooth adapter.

From early days of Windows 10 till now, I had issues connecting my Galaxy S8 to my PC. On the other hand, the S8 BT works fine.

However, whenever I tried to pair my S8 with the PC:

1. I get the prompt on **both** devices about BT connectivity authorization.
2. I approve it on both devices.
3. PC prompts that S8 is paired **successfully**, and shows it as "connected" for a few seconds. Then it changes to "paired".
4. S8 says "couldn't connect" every time I tap on the PC name in Bluetooth screen.

I repeated that a million times. Even tried with the Sony driver for Windows 8.1.

I convinced myself that this is either a hardware or driver issue, so I purchased a Bluetooth dongle (Orico BT-409). It is detected by Windows 10 just fine, but even with that, and after removing both from PC and phone and pairing again, the above message (couldn't connect) appears again even though I've turned the PC's internal BT adapter off.

Perhaps there's something with the S8 and not my PC after all?

Comment: What do you want to do using Bluetooth between phone and PC? The number of useful Bluetooth services/profiles in that scenario is as far as I know very limited.

Comment: Microsoft Your Phone app. And I didn't ask for use case advise.